# Instance of Show for lambda-abstraction ADT

Tags: haskell, instance, show, typeclass

So, I have already defined the lambda data type as such:

```
data LExpr
    = Variable String         -- variable
    | Apply LExpr LExpr       -- function application
    | Lambda String LExpr     -- Lambda abstraction 
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now I want to implement an instance of `Show` myself. I have already the function `show'` which does most of the work, but without using instances:

```
 show' :: LExpr -> String
 show' (Variable a) = a
 show' (Apply e1 e2) = "(" ++ show' e1 ++ " " ++ show' e2 ++ ")"                   
 show' (Lambda x e) = "(λ " ++ x ++ ". " ++ show' e ++ ")"
```

How I can implement it, to get the following output without using explicitly the `show'` function:

```
Main> (Apply (Lambda "x" (Apply (Variable "x") (Variable "y"))) (Variable "z"))
((λ x. x y) y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an instance declaration for the `Show` class.

```
instance Show LExpr where
  show = show'
```

And remove the `deriving(Show)` part

```
data LExpr
    = Variable String         -- variable
    | Apply LExpr LExpr       -- function application
    | Lambda String LExpr     -- Lambda abstraction 
    deriving (Eq)
```